TikZ how to temporarily discontinue line at intersection of two lines
I am working in TikZ and I am trying to make one line stop, then start again before and after the intersection with another line. I have attempted to put a node at the intersection point and filled it with white, but this has cut both lines. I only want the blue line to break and the black line to continue. Any help would be great!
Here's what the following code does:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.misc, positioning, shapes.geometric, intersections}%

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b1] (0,-1) -- (10,-1);
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b2] (0,-0.5) -- (10,-0.5);
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b3] (0,0) -- (10,0);
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b4] (0,0.5) -- (10,0.5);
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b5] (0,1) -- (10,1);

    \node[trapezium,
    draw = black,
    thick,
    rotate=90,
    minimum width = 2.5cm,
    minimum height= 1cm,
    trapezium left angle = 100,
    trapezium right angle = 80,
    trapezium stretches=true,
    trapezium stretches body =true,
    name path = trap1] (t) at (1,0) {};
    
    \draw[name intersections={of=b1 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \draw[name intersections={of=b2 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \draw[name intersections={of=b3 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \draw[name intersections={of=b4 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \draw[name intersections={of=b5 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This is the sort of thing the TikZ library spath3 was designed for.

@AndrewStacey Hi Andrew, I thought the same thing, but here the trapezoid is a node, I haven't figured out how to do it in this case! Is this possible?

@AndréC you can save the path from a node, just as with a normal path. The only bit to be aware of is that you have to save it globally because the node's path is constructed inside a group.

@AndrewStacey Interesting. I didn't know that and I don't know how to do that. Can you give an example here?

@AndréC I will do, when I'm at a suitable device.

@AndréC spath3 answer added

Here's a solution using the spath3 TikZ library.  Using this, we can define the relevant paths, add gaps at the relevant places, and then draw them afterwards.
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/715947/86}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
  shapes.misc,
  positioning,
  shapes.geometric,
  intersections,
  spath3
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]

% Create and save the arrow paths
\foreach \k in {1,...,5} {
  \path [spath/save global=b\k] (0,-1.5 + \k/2) -- ++(10,0);
}

% Create the trapezium shape
\node[
  trapezium,
    rotate=90,
    minimum width = 2.5cm,
    minimum height= 1cm,
    trapezium left angle = 100,
    trapezium right angle = 80,
    trapezium stretches=true,
    trapezium stretches body =true,
    spath/save global=trap1
] (t) at (1,0) {};

% Split the trapezium and each of the arrows where they meet,
% then insert gaps in the arrow paths at one of the intersections,
% then remove the split in the arrow paths where we didn't insert a gap.
\foreach \k in {1,...,5} {
  \tikzset{
    spath/split globally at intersections={trap1}{b\k},
    spath/insert gaps globally after components={b\k}{5pt}{1},
    spath/spot weld globally={b\k},
  }
}

% This inserts the gaps in the trapezium path, we make an alias style
% just to shorten the code.
\tikzset{
  do stuff/.style={
    spath/insert gaps after components={trap1}{5pt}{#1},
  },
  do stuff/.list={5,6,7,8,9},
}

% Now render the arrow paths
\foreach \k in {1,...,5} {
  \draw[spath/use=b\k, ->, RoyalBlue];
}

% Now render the trapezium path
\draw[black,thick,spath/use=trap1];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Here's the result:


Thank you @andrewStacey. Whilst I didn't need this solution in this project,  I will need this for future projects. This is going to be useful.

I know it is only a workaround but you could use that node twice: first for intersections, and second to actually draw it.
To make things a bit easier you can also add a style for the node so you can reuse it any time you need. The same can be done with coordinates, such that such you can have named coordinates for multiple usage.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.misc, positioning, shapes.geometric, intersections}%

\tikzset{
    tnode/.style = {
        trapezium,
        thick,
        rotate=90,
        minimum width = 2.5cm,
        minimum height= 1cm,
        trapezium left angle = 100,
        trapezium right angle = 80,
        trapezium stretches=true,
        trapezium stretches body =true,
        name path = trap1,
    },
 }


\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (ct) at (1,0);
    \node[tnode] (t) at (ct) {};
    
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b1] (0,-1) -- (10,-1);
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b2] (0,-0.5) -- (10,-0.5);
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b3] (0,0) -- (10,0);
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b4] (0,0.5) -- (10,0.5);
    \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path = b5] (0,1) -- (10,1);

    \draw[name intersections={of=b1 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \draw[name intersections={of=b2 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \draw[name intersections={of=b3 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \draw[name intersections={of=b4 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};
    \draw[name intersections={of=b5 and trap1}] (intersection-1) node[fill=white] {};

    \node [tnode, draw] at (ct) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


EDIT. Example based on scope and the background layer.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows.meta,
    shapes.misc,
    positioning,
    shapes.geometric,
    intersections,
    backgrounds,        % For a background layer
}


\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
        trapezium,
        draw = black,
        thick,
        rotate=90,
        minimum width = 2.5cm,
        minimum height= 1cm,
        trapezium left angle = 100,
        trapezium right angle = 80,
        trapezium stretches=true,
        trapezium stretches body =true,
        name path = trap1,
    ] (t) at (1,0) {};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \y using {\c/2}] \n in {-2,...,2} {
            \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, name path={b\c}] (0,\y) -- (10,\y);
            \path [name intersections={of={b\c} and trap1, name=i}] (i-1) node[fill=white] {};
        };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks @Celdor, this is what I have done, but it is a bit more combersome than I would have liked as my code is much longer than what is shown here. Is it possible to create an invisible path, then later on draw along it instead of redrawing it? Once the path trap1 has been defined can you do something like, '\draw[trap1, black, dashed]'?

@vali.b See my EDIT. It turns out we can draw parts of the tikz picture on the background layer (requires background library). However, makes names local to the scope and not available outside. You either need to change the order elements are drawn, or use name path global to make names available outside the scope.

As to your question, it is possible to save paths in a macro, for instance \path [name path = b1, save path = \pathA] (0,-1) -- (10,-1); and then draw it somewhere else \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue, use path = \pathA];. Hope this helps.

Thank you, this works perfectly!

I'd exploit the fact that TikZ respects drawing order. The idea is to overdraw the blue arrows with white, and then drawing the trapezoid. I made a few additional enhancements.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Drawing from background to foreground.
        % Note that the blue arrows will be on top of the right side of the trapezoid.
        \draw[xshift=1cm, thick] (.5,1.2) -- (.5,-1.1);
        % \foreach loop, my favourite features in TikZ
        \foreach \y in {-1,-.5,...,1}
            \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue] (0,\y) -- (10,\y);
        % Overdrawing blue arrows with white.
        % Width is "ultra thick" (1.6pt) + "thick" (.8pt) + "ultra thick" (1.6pt).
        \draw[xshift=1cm, white, line width=4pt] (-.5,1.1) -- (-.5,-1.2);
        % The thick lines of the trapezoid's sides at the top and bottom right corners don't look good.
        % I added line cap to make it almost unnoticeable, but still not perfect.
        \draw[xshift=1cm, thick, line cap=rect] (.5,1.2) -- (-.5,1.1) -- (-.5,-1.2) -- (.5,-1.1);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The line cap solution is still not perfect since the cap is not parallel to the y-axis. To avoid this, you can just \draw the whole trapezoid in one go or use your trapezium shape. However, this will loose the property that the blue arrows go on top of the right side of the trapezoid.

Well, working with intersections might be necessary if you need to place that image on a multicolored background, but if all the background is going to be a specific color, in this case white, you can play with the layers and use some draws as the same color of the background to emulate te cuts, then take advantage using 3D library, to not having to use a trapezoid for example, in the example I have drawn the lines in the XY plane to work with 3D plane manual positioning, then a square shape in a perpendicular plane but that is divided by the median axis, so that a part is drawn on a different layer, then in the drawing style options through a previous action you can draw a white line with a greater width than the original and the visual separation that is needed is emulated, I have increased the widths so that everything is visualized.
In this case \hooks is defined with two drawing instructions one in the background layer, that correspond to a first semi-square and the complement in normal layers; options #1 and #2 are placed so that I can place drawing properties for each one, so in the example for the first I can place both different colors, and for the third add the preaction style with a greater white width, finally the same but for any image of course all drawn in YZ planes.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,graphs,arrows.meta}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\hooks#1#2{
            \draw[#1, rounded corners=3pt, line width=2pt] (0,1.2) -| (1,0) |- (0,-1.2););
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
            \draw[#2, rounded corners=3pt, line width=2pt] (0,1.2) -| (-1,0) |- (0,-1.2);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
    
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \foreach \y in {-1,-.5,...,1}
            \draw [-Latex, RoyalBlue,line width=2pt,preaction={draw=white,line width=3.5pt}] (0,\y) -- (7,\y);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0.75]
            \hooks{blue}{red}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=2]
            \hooks{black}{black}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=3.25]
            \hooks{green!50!blue,preaction={draw=white,line width=3.5pt,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt}}{green!50!blue}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=5]
            \clip(2.5,1.5) rectangle (0,-1.5);
            \draw(0,0)node[transform shape]{\includegraphics[height=2.2cm]{example-image-duck}};
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
                \clip(-2.5,1.5) rectangle (0,-1.5);
                \draw(0,0)node[transform shape]{\includegraphics[height=2.2cm]{example-image-duck}};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}

